# login from xml using C#?

Tags: c#, listview

loging from C# windows by autheticating users from XML having a problem.

and returns the error "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`."

near " `string userName = user["username"].InnerText;`"

the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
  <user username="husye">
    <password>husuko</password>
    <author>Admin</author>
    <name>Hussein</name>
    <mobile>0916821918</mobile>
  </user>
  <user username="usminuru">
    <password>123</password>
    <author>Admin</author>
    <name>Ismail</name>
    <mobile>0910178976</mobile>
  </user>  
</Users>
```

The loging Form code is:

```
if (txtUserName.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Passowrd field is empty!");
                ClearTextBoxes();
            }

            int i = 0; // we use this variable to count if ther’s a user with this name

            XmlDocument myXml=new XmlDocument();

            myXml.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/AppUsers/Users.xml");            

            XmlNodeList userList = myXml.SelectNodes("Users/user");

            foreach(XmlNode user in userList)

            {

                string userName = user["username"].InnerText;

                string userPassword = user["password"].InnerText;

                string userAuthor = user["author"].InnerText;

                if (userName == txtUserName.Text)

                {

                    ++i;

                    if (userPassword == txtPassword.Text)

                    {

                        Form panel;

                        this.Opacity = 0;

                        switch(userAuthor)

                        {   

                            case "Admin":

                                panel = new MainWindow();

                                panel.Show();

                                break;

                            case "Assistant" :

                                panel = new Report();

                                panel.Show();

                                break;

                        }

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password!");
                        ClearTextBoxes();

                    }
```

Previously I have tried and works fine using elements value only for username. But this have attribute value for username.

Please help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what isn't working. Where does the error occur? And what is the error message? Also, creating a login this way is highly unsafe, please look at better ways to do this.

Comment: you are right, Just I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 string userName = user["username"].InnerText;
```

Use

```
 string userName = user.Attributes["username"].Value;
```

Also, rewrite your questions to be more readable...